# Finding area of rectangle with height 'x' enclosed within triangle of height 'h' and base 'b'

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, rectangles

A rectangle with a height *x* is drawn with its base lying on the base of the triangle. The triangle has an altitude with height *h* and the length of its base is *b*. How can I calculate the area of the enclosed rectangle in terms of these three variables?

[image: diagram here]

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: If you haven't already, drawing a picture often helps.

Comment: @user264745 I really have no idea how to begin attempting the question.

Comment: So you need to find $DE$. Since $DE||BC$, then you have similar triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bigtriangleup{AXC} \sim \bigtriangleup{EFC}$ [by $AA$ corollary] 
Thus $\frac{AX}{XC}=\frac{EF}{FC} \Rightarrow \frac{h}{XC} =\frac{x}{FC} \Rightarrow \frac{XC}{h} =\frac{FC}{x} $
Similarly for $\bigtriangleup{AXB} \sim \bigtriangleup{DGB}$:-
$\frac{AX}{XB} = \frac{DG}{GB} \Rightarrow \frac{h}{XB}=\frac{x}{GB} \Rightarrow \frac{XB}{h}=\frac{GB}{x}$
Now add the above two equations:-
$$\frac{XB+XC}{h}=\frac{FC+GB}{x}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{b}{h} = \frac{b-GF}{x}$$
$$\Rightarrow b-GF = \frac{bx}{h}$$
$$\Rightarrow GF = b-\frac{bx}{h}$$
So the area of the rectangle is $x[b-\frac{bx}{h}]\Rightarrow xb[1-\frac{x}{h}]$